# HTTP API inside docker container is very slow

Tags: java, python, docker, http

Hi i am not a docker expert and hoping someone can help we have a http API that we dockerized the throughput is very low. Following is a performance test. The same service on another environment has a TPS of around 130.
The service internally not make call to any api outside the same network. There are calls outside the container one is to Redis and the 2nd one is to another microservice both within same network.

Any one knows what are the optimal settings for docker networking what should be our starting point to trouble shoot.

```
    ./wrk -s scripts/submitsm2.py -d 300 -c 100 -t 6 http://127.0.0.1:1402
Running 5m test @ http://127.0.0.1:1402
  6 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.32s   369.60ms   1.87s    57.14%
    Req/Sec    18.34     36.43   150.00     85.38%
  2886 requests in 5.00m, 546.76KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 2872
Requests/sec:      9.62
Transfer/sec:      1.82KB
```